# Why does Go have a "bit clear (AND NOT)" operator?

Tags: go, operators, bitwise-operators

Why does Go have `&^`, the "bit clear (AND NOT)" operator?

Is there ever any difference between `a &^ b` and `a & ^b`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a subtle difference that makes dealing with literals and untyped constants easier with the explicit bit clear operator.

Untyped integers have their default type as int so something like `a := uint32(1) & ^1` is illegal as ^1 is evaluated first and it's evaluated as ^int(1), which equals -2. `a := uint32(1) &^ 1` is legal however as here 1 is evaluated as uint32, based on the context.

There could also be some performance gains in having an explicit bit clear, but I'm not too sure about that.

Comment: At least on amd64 they compile to the same machine code, so there's no performance difference there.

Comment: JimB, I assume you mean if you make everything signed ints?